# Magento 2: get product price/special price with Tax?

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

With Magento 1, you could do the following to get the price of a product with tax:

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_taxHelper  = $this->helper('tax');
$final_price = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice(), true);
```

How do I do the same in Magento 2 within a .phtml file? The prices that are set in the backend are EX vat so I'd need the price to get the relevant tax rate and multiply it to get the price inc vat. I read somewhere that Magento does this automatically however I can't seem to get it to pull the amount and I really don't want to do it manually (hardcode a tax amount as a variable and multiply the variable by the price variable).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked the default configuration setting for the tax provided by Magento?
Go to Store > configuration > sales > tax > tax classes > Price display setting > Display product price in catalog set to Including Tax

Comment: @JaydeepCharadva Yeah, I've checked through the configuration and filtered through the different store views we have in place and it's all set to include Tax.

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 using knockout. For this, you can edit html file.

For example:

**Path:** app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme_Name/Magento_Checkout/web/template/checkout/summary/item/details.html

```
<span class="price" data-bind="text: getFormattedPrice($parent.price_incl_tax)"></span>
```

Or maybe, this topic can help you.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173028/magento-2-minicart-display-line-item-subtotal-rather-than-unit-price